# How can I force a field to be required if another field has a certain value?

Tags: entities

I have two fields, a select list of checkboxes and a taxonomy term reference.  I would like the taxonomy term reference to be optional unless one of the checkboxes has a certain value, in which case a value must be entered into the taxonomy term reference field.

Is there a module that can accomplish this?  I tried the [Field Validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module but I couldn't find a way to configure it for this use case.  Custom code is fine too if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With custom code you can do something like this:

add a new validation function using hook_form_alter()

```
your_module_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'the_form_ID') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'your_custom_validation_function';
  }
}
```

then check to see if the conditions are met

```
function your_custom_validation_function($form, &$form_state){
  if( $form_state['values']['your_checkbox_name'] == 1 ) {
    // check to see if tags are set
    // use form_set_error('tags_field_id', 'error message') to set a error message
  }
}
```